# VUE using axios- data received from server but not shown

Tags: vue.js, axios

data received from server and successfully showed on first time (mounted)
but when click a href, data received but not shown.
this is my code:

```
const url = ajxurl + JSON.stringify({act:'storiesNAV', sub:i, psi:psi});
        // send axios request
        var storiesNAV = new Vue ({
            el: '#stories',
            data: {res:[]},
            methods: {
            greet: function (event) {
                    event.preventDefault();
                    axios.get(url).then(response=>{
                        console.log(response.data);
                        this.data=response.data;
                    });
            }
        },
            mounted () {axios.get(url).then(response=>{
                console.log(response.data);
                this.res=response.data;
            });},

        });
```

and this is html :

```
<div class="items">
            <a :href="'stories/'+i.id+''#" v-for="(i) in res">
              <div class="icon" :style="{'background-image':'url(res/img/stories/'+ i.iid + '/icon.png)'}"></div>
              <p>{{i.title}}</p>
              <div class="bg" :style="{'background-color':'#'+ i.bgcolor }"></div>
            </a>
          </div>
```

any help ?? what i am doing wrong ??

**### Edit**

the problem was with passing variables to VUE method, this is my complete VUE code to update html content with click function:

```
storiesNAV = new Vue ({
            el:'#stories',
            data:{
                res:[],
                loading:true,
                items:false,
            },
            mounted () { this.upDate('1'); },
      methods:{
          upDate: function(i, e='') {
                    this.loading = true;
                    this.items = false;
                    const url = Core.SetURL({act:'storiesNAV',sub:i});
            axios.get(url).then(response => {
                        this.loading = false;
                        this.items = true;
              this.res = response.data;
            });
          },
      }
        });
```

and this is HTML :

```
<div class="result" v-cloak>
          <div class="items" v-if="items">
            <a :href="'stories/'+ i.id +''#" v-for="i in res">
              <div class="icon" :style="{'background-image':'url(res/img/stories/'+ i.iid +'/icon.png)'}"></div>
              <p>{{i.title}}</p>
              <div class="bg" :style="{'background-color':'#'+ i.bgcolor }"></div>
            </a>
          </div>
        </div>
```

its working great now, I Hope This Helps someone.

Comment: try `this.res=response.data;this.res.slice();`

Comment: this works too, thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

When you mounted you have this:

```
mounted () {axios.get(url).then(response=>{
                console.log(response.data);
                this.res=response.data;
            });},
```

In your method you have:

```
greet: function (event) {
                    event.preventDefault();
                    axios.get(url).then(response=>{
                        console.log(response.data);
                        this.data=response.data;
                    });
```

Change `this.data` to `this.res`, because `res` is your array variable.

Comment: thanks for your time and quick answer, the problem was with passing variables to VUE method